# Is it possible to migrate local mail from Thunderbird to Exchange?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, exchange

I've been using Thunderbird for a few years, and have accumulated ~2GB of mail locally.  My mail service is being migrated to an externally hosted Exchange server with ample storage.  I'd like to migrate all my old messages to that server, where they will remain.  Is there a way to do this?

I care mainly about migrating the messages, and their folder structure if at all possible.  I'm not concerned with contacts or any secondary stuff from Thunderbird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Exchange server supports IMAP, add it as an account to Thunderbird, then drag and drop your messages to the remote mail folders.

If the Exchange server does not support IMAP, beat your sysadmin.